# when a user clicks a link how to redirect to a middleware then the original URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well, each user has a  show page where he post links . so If a user clicks on a link it redirects to an analytic page briefly (as twitter-analytics) then redirects to the link original destination .. .

User model

```
has_many :links
```

User controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@links = @user.links
```

user show view :

```
<%= @links.each do |x| %>
<% x.link %>
<% end %>
```